# read command function with while loop

Tags: c, do-while

I have written a read command function.It stored the characters into the array before the word "go"(start in a new line) and it returns the number of characters but it seems that the first word is always not detected and sometimes it returns without identifying the word "go". Can anyone help me. Greatly appreciated!

```
int read_command(char *input){
    char inputarr[1000];
    int count=0; 

    do
    {
        inputarr[count++]=getchar();
        input++;
    }while(inputarr[count-2]!='\n'&&inputarr[count-1]!='g'&& inputarr[count]!='o');

    inputarr[count--]='\0';
    inputarr[count--]='\0';

    for (int i=0 ;inputarr[i]!='\0';i++) {
        printf("%c",inputarr[i]);
    }

    return count;
}
```

typical output:

1.

```
I like apple and how about you
go

 like apple and how about you
29Program ended with exit code: 0
```

2.

```
I like today's weather 
and it is very sunny

 like today's weather 
22Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please show us a [MCVE] and format your code properly. Show at least how you call `read_command` and the declaration of the relevant variables.

Comment: Two things: The [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) function returns an `int`. And you don't check for `EOF`. And those two things are related, [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an `int` just to make the comparison against `EOF` work.

Comment: Your while loop is dereferencing a negative number as the index for inputarr on the first iteration.

Comment: By the way, in the first iteration when `count == 1` you have `inputarr[count-2]!='\n'`. That will be using index `-1` in your array which is *out of bounds*. You also have no check for going out of bounds in the other direction.

Comment: Your code is essentially ignoring the `input` parameter to the function (just incrementing it doesn't count).  If the function should be writing to the array, then eliminate `inputarr`, but also pass the size of `input` to the function, and check for overflows.

Comment: Observation: it would probably be simplest to read whole lines (`fgets()`, and check whether the last line is `go`.  Presumably, that `go` should be followed by a newline (as well as preceded by it) so that texts discussing `gophers` and `going places` where these appear at the start of a line are not treated as the `go` end-of-command.  You might need to consider what should happen if the first line entered is `go`; there won't be a newline before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not handled all the scenarios properly - 
1. What if "go" is in first line itself?
2. What if there is first word in sentence which start with "go" sub string?
3. At the start, you cannot check inputarr[count-2] as it will be negative value.
You can refer following program in which, if you type "go" and press enter then it will print all the lines-

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{   int c='\0';
    char ch[100];
    int i=0;
    while (c != EOF){
        c = getchar();
        ch[i]=c;
        i++;
        printf("<%c>\n",c);
        if(i >= 3 && ch[i-1] == 'o' && ch[i-2] == 'g' && ch[i-3] == '\n'){
            int j;
            for(j=0;j<i-2;j++){
                printf("%c",ch[j]);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```